# Getting KeyError when trying to access key in a dictionary

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, dictionary, boto3, aws-sdk

I'm using Boto3 of AWS to describe the security group and trying to access the `FromPort` key for all the security groups available in a particular region. But when I'm trying to do so it will list some of the ports and then throws the `KeyError`.

Code:

```
import boto3
    
client = boto3.client('ec2')
response = client.describe_security_groups()

for sg in response['SecurityGroups']:
    for ip in sg['IpPermissions']:
        print(ip['FromPort'])
```

Output:

```
80
5432
22
22
3622
8443
3
80
3622
8080
5432
22
8443
443
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\a.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(ip['FromPort'])
KeyError: 'FromPort'
```

Comment: I think that one of your dictionnary doesn't have a FromPort key. Try to print all the keys of this particular one. You can also put a condition before you print the value to ignore if the key doesn't exist*

Comment: Welcome to SO.  From what I can see, ```FromPort``` doesn't exist for one particular entry.  Try printing out the value of ```ip``` before each item.

Comment: @BoarGules thnx its working please add this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is assuming that the entry you are trying to print is always in the response you get back. You can make the code more robust like this:

Replace

```
ip['FromPort']
```

with

```
ip.get('FromPort','((missing))')
```